# Does &$this is really disallowed to use anywhere?

Tags: oop, optimization

I got this message from the validator of plugins from Envato:

> 1. When creating a callable, never use &$this, use $this instead:
>      [image: https://envato.d.pr/uDWuiT]

I think he may be wrong with his '**never use**'. Are we really NOT SAVING a memory when we are passing an object by reference? Can only clarify on this?

Thank you.

Comment: P.S. Can anyone add tag 'passing-by-reference' here, as I'm not allowed.

Comment: No, we really don't need this tag! :)

Comment: Oh, and `&$this` is PHP 4 syntax. WordPress requires version 5 or 7 in which objects are always passed by reference.